# Escaping loads of characters going into MySQL

Tags: php, mysqli

I've got an HTML form into which a user can enter an SQL query.

The query needs to be entered into a field of my MYSql database. But for complex queries that include % _ , ; ' " $ < > etc... it fails.

How would i go about entering this info into the DB without error?

I know the below is not a very secure way to do it, for now, I just need it to work :)

```
// Get values from form 
$username = $_SESSION['user']; 
$appname = $_POST['appname'];
$sql2 = $_POST['sql'];


// Insert data into mysql 
$sqlquery="INSERT INTO puresql (username,appnm, query)VALUES('$username','$appname', '$sql2')";
$result=mysqli_query($dbconn,$sqlquery);
```

Comment: Fixing the security problems will fix the error.

Comment: Use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else with this issue. the below works, using mysqli_real_escape_string

```
$date = date("Y/m/d");
echo "$date";
$appname = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconn, $_POST['appname']);
$sql2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconn, $_POST['sql']);
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconn, $_SESSION['user']);

// Insert data into mysql 
$sqlquery="INSERT INTO livepurespark (username,appnm, query, date)VALUES('$username','$appname', '$sql2', '$date')";
$result=mysqli_query($dbconn,$sqlquery);
```

Comment: Do not use `mysqli_real_escape_string`, use [prepared statements](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score 0):

Another way of saving complex texts in database fields with added benefit of protection from sql injection is by using parameterized query statements (Prepared Statements).

```
$username = $_SESSION['user']; 
$appname = $_POST['appname'];
$sql2 = $_POST['sql'];

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbconn, "INSERT INTO puresql (username,appnm, query)VALUES('?','?','?')");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $username, $appname, $sql2);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```